# Vmware ESXi change datastore to SSD

Tags: vmware-esxi

I've been trying to reconfigure vmware to recognize a datastore as SSD strorage.  I've found several articles regarding this:

[VmwareKB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2013188), [Virtually Ghetto](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2011/07/how-to-trick-esxi-5-in-seeing-ssd.html), [Storage Monk](http://storagemonk.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-tagenable-device-as-ssd-in-esxi.html).  However i'm running into issues:

When I run:

```
esxcli storage nmp satp rule add --satp SATP --device naa.6842b2b02599aa00181935940bbfce4c --option "enable_ssd"
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Invalid option enable_ssd
```

If I run

```
esxcli storage nmp satp rule add --satp SATP --device naa.6842b2b02599aa00181935940bbfce4c --option "enable_ssd"
```

I get the error:

```
Plugin 'SATP' is not a registered SATP. Please select a plugin from the list in
'esxcli storage core plugin registration list -N SATP' or use the --force option
 to force the use of this SATP.
```

I attempted to use the --force command and can see the rule if I run

```
~ # esxcli storage nmp satp rule list | grep enable_ssd
SATP                 naa.6842b2b02599aa00181935940bbfce4c                                                  enable_ssd                  user
```

However the datastore is still coming up as non-ssd.  Any ideas or easier ways to accomplish this ?  Thanks

---

Edit Output of esxcli storage nmp device list

```
naa.6842b2b02599aa00181935940bbfce4c
   Device Display Name: Local DELL Disk (naa.6842b2b02599aa00181935940bbfce4c)
   Storage Array Type: VMW_SATP_LOCAL
   Storage Array Type Device Config: SATP VMW_SATP_LOCAL does not support device configuration.
   Path Selection Policy: VMW_PSP_FIXED
   Path Selection Policy Device Config: {preferred=vmhba1:C2:T0:L0;current=vmhba1:C2:T0:L0}
   Path Selection Policy Device Custom Config:
   Working Paths: vmhba1:C2:T0:L0
   Is Local SAS Device: false
   Is Boot USB Device: false
~ # naa.6842b2b02599aa00181935940bbfce4c
```

Comment: In the examples 'SATP' is just a variable that is to be replaced by the real SATP value (e.g. VMW_SATP_CX), and this is displayed by "esxcli storage nmp device list". What is the output of this command on your host?

Comment: @VFrontDe See Edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is probably a small local installation, did you follow the last step in the [VMware KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2013188)?

***You must reboot the ESXi host to tag the local datastore (if ESXi is installed locally) as the SSD drive.***

Comment: did try a reboot to no avail

Comment: See the [comment on your question](http://serverfault.com/questions/543658/vmware-esxi-change-datastore-to-ssd#comment626604_543658). The example you used possibly has different values than your system's values.

Answer (score 2):

You are meant to replace SATP with the SATP of the device as displayed in the Storage Array Type field - in this case `VMW_SATP_LOCAL`.  The directions aren't the clearest.

The following should work for you: `esxcli storage nmp satp rule add --satp VMW_SATP_LOCAL --device naa.6842b2b02599aa00181935940bbfce4c --option=enable_ssd`